USB drive is not recognized due to a failed partition formatting
(sorry for my poor English)
I created a encrypted partition on my Kingston USB drive (/dev/sda) using VeraCrypt.
I was trying to format the partition using GNOME Disk Utility after mounted the partition using VeraCrypt (/dev/sda2 -> /dev/mapper/veracrypt1 -> /mnt/crypt), but I got an error.
Now, my USB drive is not recognized by my computer (runs PopOS 22.04 LTS and Windows 11).
GNOME Disk Utility show a device /dev/sda with no size.
Command df, fdisk, testdisk, dd, fsck, e2fsck can not find the medium /dev/sda.
Command lsblk found the device sda, but size is 0:
NAME          MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
loop0           7:0    0   173M  0 loop  /run/wine
sda             8:0    1     0B  0 disk  
nvme0n1       259:0    0   1.9T  0 disk  
├─nvme0n1p1   259:1    0   512M  0 part  
├─nvme0n1p2   259:2    0    16M  0 part  
├─nvme0n1p3   259:3    0   100G  0 part  
├─nvme0n1p4   259:4    0   100G  0 part  
├─nvme0n1p5   259:5    0 193.1G  0 part  /
├─nvme0n1p6   259:6    0   1.5T  0 part  /mnt/evil
└─nvme0n1p7   259:7    0     8G  0 part  
  └─cryptswap 252:0    0     8G  0 crypt [SWAP]

Command sudo dmesg | tail output this:
[16040.588575] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[16040.588585] usb 2-1: Product: USB DISK 53X            
[16040.588587] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: Phison                  
[16040.589537] usb-storage 2-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[16040.590135] scsi host0: usb-storage 2-1:1.0
[16041.608399] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     13FE     USB DISK 50X     PMAP PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
[16041.608989] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[16041.609425] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Media removed, stopped polling
[16041.609972] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
[16961.241573] workqueue: delayed_fput hogged CPU for >10000us 1024 times, consider switching to WQ_UNBOUND

Command lsusb also found the device:
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 011: ID 0b05:18c6 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. N-KEY Device
Bus 003 Device 009: ID 13d3:5492 IMC Networks USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 04f3:0c6e Elan Microelectronics Corp. ELAN:Fingerprint
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 0416:5020 Winbond Electronics Corp. USB Device
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0c45:636d Microdia USB 2.0 Camera
Bus 003 Device 042: ID 05ac:024f Apple, Inc. Aluminium Keyboard (ANSI)
Bus 003 Device 041: ID 5131:2019 MSR 
Bus 003 Device 040: ID 25a7:fa61 Areson Technology Corp Elecom Co., Ltd MR-K013 Multicard Reader
Bus 003 Device 039: ID 1a40:0801 Terminus Technology Inc. USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 214b:7250 Huasheng Electronics USB2.0 HUB
Bus 003 Device 012: ID 8087:0033 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 13fe:5500 Kingston Technology Company Inc. Flash drive
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Bus 002 Device 007: ID 13fe:5500 Kingston Technology Company Inc. Flash drive

GUI tools like GParted and DiskGenius can not recognize the device.
Can anyone PLEASE tell me what should I do now?

size is 0 [sda] Media removed, stopped polling in the case of a thumb drive, this pretty much means the drive is dead (or at least, bricked). (You may try something like sg_start --load, although it's very unlikely that it would help.)

@TomYan thank you. nothing happened indeed. :(

You can try dd of beginning of drive, to see if then you can create partition(s). sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX bs=512 count=1 where sdX is your correct drive like sda. Double check that is correct, dd's nickname is data destroyer as if you have wrong drive it still erases partition table. Best use 'sudo parted -l` just before running dd. My flash drives often change from sdc to sda on reboot. https://askubuntu.com/questions/939230/formatting-a-usb-stick-unable-to-operate-usb/939266#939266 &
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb#Re-use_the_pendrive &

@oldfred Maybe it is dead. dd: error writing '/dev/sda': No space left on device
